# NPM and Sanctioned "Man in the Middle" Activites

Tags: node.js, npm, ssl-certificate

My company does the "Man in the Middle" thing so they can see what all employees do even on SSL sites.

Yesterday I tried to use Node Package Manager for the first time at work.  (I have used it successfully from home before.)

So when I tried to run it to get the Gulp package, I got an error:

> SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

I am fairly sure this is because my company has their own certificate between me and the actual NPM site.

**Is there some way to tell NPM that even though the certificate is self signed it is ok and to continue on anyway?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm config set strict-ssl false` to enable globally.

or

`npm install --strict-ssl=false ...` to just disable strict SSL checks on one npm install

Comment: Thank you!  That worked for direct NPM calls.  **Do you know if there is a way to do this for JSPM calls?**  (I set that up then ran JSPM and it is still complaining about self signed Certificates for NPM items. (font-awesome in my case))